# Filter one table based on another in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one `table(1)` that looks like this (it is an all by all distance `matrix transformed` into a tab separated list):

```
sample1    sample2    405
sample3    sample4    400
sample5    sample6    1
sample7    sample8    20
sample1    sample3    40
```

I have another `table(2)` which contains those samples which meet a certain criteria:

```
sample1
sample2
sample8
```

How can I parse the first `table(1)` to extract only those rows in which both the variables in columns `1` and `2` can be found in `table(2)`?

ie desired comparisons are only:

```
sample1    sample2    405
sample2    sample8    40
sample8    sample1    100
```

Comment: The desired comparisions does not make any sense to me. Is that what you want as output? Or those values are not accurate?

Comment: sorry the values are made up - I just want to filter table(1) for all vs all pairwaise comparisons only for values found in table(2)

Comment: Understood. `dplyr` can be used to join `data.frame`

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
rawData1 <- "first second distance
 sample1    sample2    405
 sample3    sample4    400
 sample5    sample6    1
 sample7    sample8    20
 sample1    sample3    40"

rawData2 <- "sample
 sample1
 sample2
 sample8"

a <- read.table(textConnection(rawData1),stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE)
b <- read.table(textConnection(rawData2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE)

a[a$first %in% b$sample & a$second %in% b$sample, ]
```

...and the output:

```
> a[a$first %in% b$sample & a$second %in% b$sample, ]
    first  second distance
1 sample1 sample2      405
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a similar set-up using a dataframe for your table(1) and a vector for your table(2).

```
table_one <- data.frame(col_1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
       col_2 = c("b", "d", "f", "g"),
       col_3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
table_two <- c("b", "d")
```

When you set it up that way, something like this should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
table_one %>% filter(col_1 %in% table_two,
                     col_2 %in% table_two)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option could be `inner_join` twice, both with 1st column and 2nd column and then perform `intersect` of two result set.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- read.table(text = "Samp1 Samp2  Val
sample1    sample2    405
sample3    sample4    400
sample5    sample6    1
sample7    sample8    20
sample1    sample3    40", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df1
    Samp1   Samp2 Val
1 sample1 sample2 405
2 sample3 sample4 400
3 sample5 sample6   1
4 sample7 sample8  20
5 sample1 sample3  40

df2 <- data.frame(Samp = c("sample1",
                           "sample2",
                           "sample8"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df2
     Samp
1 sample1
2 sample2
3 sample8

#use inner_join between Samp1 with Samp and then again Samp2 with Samp
intersect(inner_join(df1,df2, by = c("Samp1" = "Samp")),
      inner_join(df1,df2, by = c("Samp2" = "Samp")))

The result will be:
    Samp1   Samp2 Val
1 sample1 sample2 405
```

Comment: I think that the result set should only contain distances where both `Samp1` AND `Samp2` are in  `df2$Samp`, which is different than what is produced by your code. If you use `intersect()` instead of `union()` your code produces the correct output.

Comment: @LenGreski You have pointed out correctly. If `Samp1` and `Samp2` both should be in `df$Samp` then `intersect()` will be needed.